# coordinates in front of me (webgl / opengl)

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I'm learning webgl and I've been stuck on this problem for half a day.

I'm moving into my scene this way :

```
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(-angle), [0, 1, 0]); 
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-currentX, 0, -currentZ]);
```

How am I supposed to get the coordinates (x/z) of a point in front of me (let's say 10 units) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modelview matrix is the matrix the transforms from model local space to view space. Now a point "10 units in front of you" can be anywhere, depending on the space you're interested in. But say you want to know where a point 10 units in front of you was located in model space. Well, nothing as simple as that.

The point 10 units in front of the viewer is located in view space at (0,0,-10). So all you have to do now is applying the inverse transform, i.e. multiply that vector with the inverse ov mvMatrix:

```
mat4.inverse(mvMatrix) * vec4(0,0,-10,1);
```

If you wonder where the last `1` element comes from and why a 4 element vector is used for a 3 dimensional coordinate (which is something you should really wonder about) have a read about [homogenous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics).